# Book for Astrophysics

Tags: mathematical-physics, astrophysics, resource-recommendations, astronomy, relativity

I need a book for cosmology, I need this book to be deep in the physical meanings and in the mathematical proofs.

I also need a cosmology book talking about the universe from a to z (till special and general relativity or more if exist).

Comment: Why does your title & tags say astrophysics but the body cosmology? Which is it?

Answer (score 1):

There are infinitely many books on cosmology. Among most widely known are:

1) Weinberg "Cosmology";

2) Mukhanov "Physical Foundations of Cosmology";

3) Gorbunov and Rubakov "Introduction to the Theory of the Early Universe";

4) Baumann and McAllister "Inflation and String Theory".

Comment: are all of these deep on physics and math

Comment: @user288086 Cosmology is based on GR, and essentially it is about solving and analyzing Einstein equations for various matter content. If you are interested in mathematical aspects of the topic, you should study books on foundations of GR. Check, for example, Fre "Gravity, a Geometrical Course".

Comment: what is meant by GR

Comment: @user288086 General Relativity.

Comment: These do not follow our book recommendations template. Please add details about the books (e.g., level of audience, writing style, etc), otherwise this is liable to be deleted.